# Excel formula to assign a unique value to a column dependent on 2 other columns (First and Last name)?

Tags: excel, if-statement, organization

So I have a huge excel sheet of contact info with 30,000+ rows and I'm trying to assign each contact a unique ID based on their First and Last name (separate columns).

The statement I have right now for assigning unique values is

> IF(D3=D2),E2,E2+1)

Column D = Last Name
Column E = ID

The statement works, but it only assigns value based on last name and is reliant on only the value of the cell above. There are contacts that have their name in multiple locations, thus the formula  will give the same contact multiple IDs.

What I want to do is write a statement that assigns a unique value to a contact based on first AND last name (Columns C & D), and also have the formula assess the entire worksheet for the IF statement, rather than just the value in the cell above.

Hopefully I explained that clearly, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best option is to use a hash function for the first name and to unite it with a hash function for the second name. [This answer here provides the VBA code for the BASE64SHA1:](https://superuser.com/a/550605/495577)

```
Public Function BASE64SHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String)

    Dim asc As Object
    Dim enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Const cutoff As Integer = 5

    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

    TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    BASE64SHA1 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
    BASE64SHA1 = Left(BASE64SHA1, cutoff)
    
End Function

Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String

    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objNode As Object    
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.text
    
End Function
```

Then, just using it will result in what you need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following formula starting at row 2:

```
{=IF(COUNTIFS(C$2:C2,C2,D$2:D2,D2)=1,MAX(E$1:E1)+1,VLOOKUP(C2&D2,CHOOSE({1,2},C$2:C$13&D$2:D$13,E$2:E$13),2,FALSE))}
```

Note that this is an array formula, you will need to confirm it with `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`

A quick breakdown of what it does:

1. `COUNTIFS(C$2:C2,C2,D$2:D2,D2)=1` check to see if this is the first ocurence of the first and last name
2. If it is, we take the maximum ID number and add `1` to generate a new one with `MAX(E$1:E1)+1`
3. If it isn't we use `VLOOKUP(C2&D2,CHOOSE({1,2},C$2:C$13&D$2:D$13,E$2:E$13),2,FALSE)` to find the existing ID for that first and last name (this BTW, is the part of the formula that requires it to be an array formula)